# How to know if a list contains only 1 element without using len

Tags: python

I want to know if a list contains only one element, without using `len`.

What is the most pythonic way to do it between these two solutions? Or maybe none of these are pythonic, and if so what is then?

Solution a: remove item at position 1 and except an `IndexError` so I know there was only 1 item.

```
try:
    a_list.pop(1):
except IndexError:
    #blah
```

solution b: use slicing to remove first element and check if the list is now empty

```
if not a_list[1:]:
    # blah
```

Comment: `if len(a_list) != 1:`

Comment: `if len(a_list) == 1`

Comment: In addition to being needlessly convoluted, your first method mutates the list in the process of testing it.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I forgot to mention that I try to implement a recursive version of len to practice recursion, and therefore I dont want to use len. My bad. I dont care if I mutates the list as I only return 1 if the test fail.

Comment: If you remember something important -- edit your question. In any event -- the natural basis case for a recursive implementation of `len` would be that of length 0 (empty) rather than length 1. It is easy to test for a zero basis with `a_list == []`.

Comment: A 1-liner recursive list length function: `def length(xs): return 0 if xs == [] else 1 + length(xs[1:])` Unfortunately, it will blow the stack even for something as simple as `list(range(2000))`.

Comment: @vildric If you mutate the list in the function you will mutate the list you passed in. So if you're going to create a function that tests if a list contains one element you most likely don't want it to mutate the list.

Answer (score 9):

One of Python's philosophies is, asking for forgiveness is easier than asking for permission ([Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)).

In this sense, the most Pythonic way to check if a list has at least one element would be trying and access the element at index `0`.

```
try:
    some_list[0]
except IndexError:
    print("some_list is empty").
```

Note that `pop` mutates the list, which is not what you want in a test.

Now if you want to check if a list has *exactly* one element, a succession of `try` and `except` could do the job, but it would become unreadable.

The best way is probably a direct `len` check:

```
if len(some_list) == 1:
    print("some_list has exactly one element")
```

---

You commented that you did not want to use `len`.

I suggest you use the succession of `try` and `except` that I evoked above:

```
try:
    l[0]
except IndexError:
    print("length = 0")
else:
    try:
        l[1]
    except IndexError:
        print("length = 1")
    else:
        print("length > 1")
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I dont want to use len because I implement a recursive version of it to practice recursion, so I'll use a try/except... Thanks.

Comment: @vildric I edited your question to highlight this will. Besides, check my edit for an example.

Comment: `some_list.pop()` will mutate the list. Probably not what you want to do in this situation.

Comment: Instead of using `pop` you could just try accessing the first element and then the second. That way you don't mutate the list. Also, make sure to explicitly except only `IndexError`. If someone would pass in an integer, boolean or any other type that doesn't define `pop`, into this test it would print `length = 0`, which might be unwanted in some cases.

Comment: @AndrewGuy That's right, I just kept the same idea as OP. Still, I changed my answer according to this.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman You're right, I did not bother with this at first but surely it's a detail that must receive consideration. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to mutate the list in place (eg by using `.pop()`). To check that the list contains **only one element**, you could use a couple of `try`, `except` statements to check that **(1)** you can access the first element, and **(2)** you can't access a second element.

```
def is_single_item_list(list_to_check):
    #Check that list is not empty
    try:
        _ = list_to_check[0]
    except IndexError:
        return False
    #Return true if list has a single element
    try:
        _ = list_to_check[1]
    except IndexError:
        return True
    #Return False if more than one element
    return False
```

Really, the most Pythonic way is to just use `len`.