# Pythonic way to test single-element lists to avoid IndexErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Throughout my codebase there is a design pattern in which we have two lists of objects and try to whittle it down to one object.

Say we have two classes,

```py
class Employee():
    
    def __init__(self, _id, name):
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
    
class Shift():
    
    def __init__(self, employee_id, shift_id):
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.shift_id = shift_id
```

We have lists of objects of these classes. I want to find the employee who has a shift with their id attached to it. Suppose I have the list `employees` containing Employee objects, and the list `shifts` containing Shift objects, then I do:

```py
for shift in shifts:
    # Find employee who is assigned to this shift
    employee = [e for e in employees if e._id == shift.employee_id]
```

So far so good. There's no guarantee that the `employees_with_shift` will contain an employee though. If there is an employee, there's only one. Currently it's being handled like this:

```py
if employee:
    employee = employee[0]
    ... do something
```

But I don't think this is Pythonic. A simple solution would be to:

```py
for e in employee:
    ...do something
```

I don't know if this is unpythonic, but it does handle the case smoothly. Is it wrong to use a for-loop on lists that have either zero or one elements?

The other one is to go by AFNP and do this:

```py
try:
    employee = employee[0]
    ... do something
except IndexError:
    pass
```

I don't like this though because there is quite a lot of coding to do on the employee, and the error handling would get extremely complicated.

Which of my solutions (if any) is the most pythonic?

EDIT:
This question is not answered by the one in the close suggestion, because this question looks for the most pythonic way to handle **the element of a list** that contains either 0 or 1 elements.

Comment: Do you mean EAFP by AFNP? -- oh apparently they exist both and are the same.

Comment: Why don't the Employees just explicitly track which Shifts they work?

Comment: "Though it does handle the case smoothly, is it wrong to use a for loop on lists that have either zero or one elements?" wait, are you saying you are only ever expecting the list to have 1 or zero elements?

Comment: Would you consider looping over shifts rather?

Comment: Where do you define `employees_with_shift`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if a list contains only 1 element without using len](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927869/how-to-know-if-a-list-contains-only-1-element-without-using-len)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of first creating a list that will contain either 0 or 1 items and then unpacking the list again, I would use `next` to find the first employee matching the condition. If there is none, this will raise `StopIteration`, because the iteration of the generator expression passed into `next` is exhausted:

```
# Find employee who is assigned to this shift
try:
    employee = next(e for e in employees if e._id == shift.employee_id)
except StopIteration:
    # no such employee
```

*However*, why don't you just have a dictionary mapping employees by their ID?

Then you could simply write:

```
try:
    employee = employees[shift.employee_id]
except KeyError:
    # no such employee
```

And then you should ask yourself how it could happen that a shift was assigned an employee that doesn't exist. Maybe it's because *no* employee was assigned to the shift and `shift.employee_id` is `None`? Then LBYL would in fact be clearer IMO:

```
if shift.employee_id is None:
    # no employee was assigned yet
    return  # or continue, break, ...

# now this must succeed, if not there is a bug
assert shift.employee_id in employees
employee = employees[shift.employee_id]
```

Comment: I really like this answer, just because it uses [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). I find that it's most often easier to follow and debug code that is written in that fashion, rather than [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The StopIteration error in the try except really smooths up my code. There's a variety of reasons why some of the other answers don't answer my question (specific to my codebase, not mentioned in the q), but I think yours is the most insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @mkrieger1's answer, `next()` takes a default return value, so you can just do

```py
employee = next(e for e in employees if e._id == shift.employee_id,None)
```

This will default employee to `None` for example.

A dictionary mapping would indeed also be great:

You could avoid the `try..except` by using `.get()`:

```py
employee = employees.get(shift.employee_id,None)
```

You don't say what you want employee to default to if it's absent in the shift list though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a single object in a list, and you expect it to either be in the list or not (and not multiple possible values), then **don't create a list in the first place**. The Pythonic thing to do would be simply:

```
for employee in employees:
    if e._id == shift.employee_id:
        # handle employee
        break
else:
    # handle the case where no employee is found, else clause not necessery
    # if you simply want to pass
```

Probably the better design overall is to have a *dictionary* mapping employee id's to employees so you can handle it like this:

```
try:
    employee = employee_dict[shift.employee_id]
except KeyError:
    # handle not found case
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're already at the most pythonic point, barring an architecture restructuring, but you could always turn it into one line:

```
employee = employee[0] if bool(employee) else None
# or this is perhaps more pythonic
employee = employee[0] if employee else None
# I dislike using implicit booleans because of type ambiguity.
```

It's not much different to what you're already doing, but it would look better, and that might be enough here!

EDIT: I agree with the other answers about using a dictionary. My answer applies if you really can't do that

Comment: `if bool(employee)` -> `if employee`

Comment: I know that works but I deliberately avoid doing it as the type of `employee` is ambiguous, though not really in this case. I've edited my answer to include the option.